# Multiply a 3D array with a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a 3D numpy array and I want to multiply it with a 2D array, The 3D looks like follows:

```
C= np.zeros((3, 2, 2))
C[0][0] = [0,0]
C[0][1] = [0,1]
C[1][0] = [1,0]
C[1][1] = [1,1]
C[2][0] = [1,2]
C[2][1] = [2,1]
```

The 2D array looks like:

```
V = np.zeros((3,2)) 
V[0][0] = 1
V[0][1] = 2
V[1][0] = 1
V[1][1] = 3
V[2][0] = 4 
V[2][1] = 5
```

The result `R` is to be a 2X2 2D array(4 elements in total) `R=[[5,8],[13,10]]` where:

```
R[0] = V[0][0]*C[0][0]+V[1][0]*C[1][0]+V[2][0]*C[2][0] = [5,8] (first row of R)

R[1] = V[0][1]*C[0][1]+V[1][1]*C[1][1]+V[2][1]*C[2][1] = [13,10] (second row of R)
```

This is just an example, How Can I get `R` using numpy matrix multiplication operation with `V` and `C` (with no for loop!). Please help!

Sorry I made some edit later, the comment showed an old example, it should be good now

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243213/discussion-on-question-by-tim-lu-multiply-a-3d-array-with-a-2d-array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is confusing. Why do you say your expected result is `[[1, 0], [5, 10]]` but in your example you also say `R` should be `[[5, 8], [13, 10]]`?

I hope this was just a typo on your part because it's not clear from your example how you'd get from one to the other.

In any case:

```py
(V.T * C.T).sum(axis=2).T
```

Output:

```py
array([[ 5.,  8.],
       [13., 10.]])
```

Comment: he was trying to get me to understand what he was trying to do ...  I probably made him make it harder to understand overall (this is a great answer)

Answer (score 3):

```
In [20]: C          # (3,2,2)
Out[20]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[1, 2],
        [2, 1]]])
In [21]: V         # (3,2)
Out[21]: 
array([[1., 2.],
       [1., 3.],
       [4., 5.]])
```

Expand `V` to (3,2,1).  This `broadcasts` with `C` to produce a (3,2,2):

```
In [22]: C * V[:,:,None]
Out[22]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  2.]],

       [[ 1.,  0.],
        [ 3.,  3.]],

       [[ 4.,  8.],
        [10.,  5.]]])
```

and sum on the first axis to make (2,2) result:

```
In [23]: (C * V[:,:,None]).sum(axis=0)
Out[23]: 
array([[ 5.,  8.],
       [13., 10.]])
```

This answer cleans up @ddjohns answer; he did the hard work.

The sum-of-products can be expressed with `einsum` as:

```
In [24]: np.einsum('ijk,ij->jk',C,V)
Out[24]: 
array([[ 5.,  8.],
       [13., 10.]])
```

Reordering the axes, we can express it as a more conventional sum-of-products:

```
In [25]: np.einsum('jki,ji->jk',C.transpose(1,2,0),V.transpose(1,0))
Out[25]: 
array([[ 5.,  8.],
       [13., 10.]])
```

And use that to cast it as a `matmul`:

```
In [28]: (C.transpose(1,2,0)@V.transpose(1,0)[:,:,None]).squeeze(2)
Out[28]: 
array([[ 5.,  8.],
       [13., 10.]])
```

[28] is probably fastest, but [23] may be easier to understand.

Comment: I wanted to try finding a better way than having to use three transposes, but it was late and I wanted to go to bed :D This is a great answer.